# Access Windows 7 Shared folders on PS3

Tags: networking, ps3, playstation

I have a Windows 7 computer with few shared partitions to anyone without password requirements. Other computers and devices (such as WDTV) can access the shared partitions without problems. PS3 on other hand can't see those partitions.

How can I view those shared partitions on PS3?

P.S. I am not interested in setting up media streaming, I just need to access shared partitions form PS3 system

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out this [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727037.aspx) and seeing if the settings are correct. Note that if the win7 machine is on a "public network" the connection will fail, which is pretty common. The article goes into depth about debugging various issues that may arise.